# Neo4j cypher how to delete empty relations

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have five relationships in the database, all created in the past. Four are empty, not attached to any node. How can I delete them? I want to keep only the one I am currently using and is attached to the nodes.

Comment: Having orphan relationships seems impossible. can you show the output you have of these relationships and how you found it. Thank you.

Comment: I used this query to clean up the database: MATCH (n) OPTIONAL MATCH (n)-[r]-() DELETE n,r; The queries are not showing them anymore after deletion. But I am still getting them listed on the graphical console http://localhost:7474/browser/ on left panel under relationship types.

Comment: Ha ok, the relationships are not present. It is just that the stores hold some trace from what happened to the database in the past. The same behavior apply for node labels, they are surely also listed on the left side even if the database is empty.

Comment: I also got some nodes from, the past after I deleted physically the data folder. These ghost nodes are returned by cypher queries. How this is possible? I created those nodes, I run the delete all mentioned above. I was not happy with the remains still present, I deleted physically the data folder and I am still getting ghost relationship in the web console and ghost nodes visible in the web console but also returned by cypher queries.

Comment: make sure to refresh the browser. However deleting the /data/graph.db folder should not show this.

Comment: I already restarted the server many times so far, actually I restarted the computer also many times. Those ghost data and relationships were created couple weeks ago, at the beginning of the month, almost three weeks ago. I changed the model classes also a long time ago.

Comment: OK, I repeated the entire process again: delete query for all nodes and relationships; removed the data folder entirely, restarted the computer and the server. Now all the ghosts are gone. But I will keep this under watch for a while since first time I sow the ghosts was after several hours. Now the web interfaces are a little bit slow. Not sure what the db does in the background. I will post another comment by tomorrow.

Comment: OK; the ghost nodes are not showing up anymore. Have to figure out how to clean the web interface from non-existing relationships.

Comment: The ghost relationships are not dropped no matter what I am doing, rebooting server, browser or even the computer. These are still present in the web interface of the database. Any clue how I can loose them without removing the graph.db data file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that this is a problem with one single radical solution so far: to erase physically the database folders and files. Which I don't like it at all.

Answer (score 1):

Neo4j does not offer a direct way to get rid of labels or relationship types that are no longer in use. However you can use the batch inserter API as a offline tool to copy over the contents of your db into a fresh one.

Luckily Michael has already written a tool doing this, check out https://github.com/jexp/store-utils. Be sure to bump the Neo4j version in `pom.xml` to the one you're currently using.